# Javascript Bug in Capitalizing First Letter of Each Word in Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a small blogger and I don't have enough knowledge about Javascript.
I have a two problems related to capitalize first letter of each word while typing in textarea. Some where on Stack Overflow I've found the js code given below. It's working fine but there is a bug in that.

**Problem 1:**
When a user type in single line it capitalize all words but it does NOT capitalize first word after every line break or say when user hits the Enter to go to next line it keeps first letter small not capitalize.

**Problem 2:**
If user put a comma or full stop right before the word, then it also does not capitalize the word.

**What I Want!**
In any condition all the words should be capitalize and automatically provide a space before words if user does not give space after comma, full stop, hyphen, exclamation mark and rest of the basic special characters.

[Live Example](http://shayaris.punjabi.cc/badal-gaye-sad-shayari-on-zindagi/#respond)

Following is my code:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $.fn.capitalize = function() {
    $.each(this, function() {
      var split = this.value.split(' ');
      for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
        split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
      }
      this.value = split.join(' ');
    });
    return this;
  };
  $('input#author').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).capitalize();
  }).capitalize();
  $('textarea#comment').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).capitalize();
  }).capitalize();
});
$(window).load(function() {
  $('input#email').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea minlength="120" id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true" placeholder="Shayari"></textarea>
```

Comment: Java or Javascript?

Comment: Yes, that's what happens when you only split on blanks. What have you tried to solve the problems?

Comment: @Bergi I don't actually have knowledge about JavaScript? I need help from an expert.

Comment: Please do not use `regional` comment language. Also we will help you. No need to request anyone

Comment: I guess you should try to [learn javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) (a task at which we'll gladly help) or hire a professional. StackOverlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the suggestion, I understand your literal social thoughts. But still do you know anything about Java or you find it difficult like me?

Comment: @Laddi I know nothing about Java, but a lot about Javascript. Btw, `this.value = this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\S/g, function(m) { return m.toUpperCase(); });` should solve your issue.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, I see. If so, may you please setup the full code? I believe that you can write a well optimized and efficient code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to update your code as following

```
$(window).load(function() {

  $.fn.capitalize = function() {
    $.each(this, function() {
      var lines = this.value.split('\n');
      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          var split = lines[i].split(' ');
          for (var j = 0, len = split.length; j < len; j++) {
            split[j] = split[j].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[j].slice(1).toLowerCase();
          }

          lines[i] = split.join(' ');
      }
      this.value = lines.join('\n');
    });
    return this;
  };

  $('input#author').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var $control = $(e.currentTarget);
    // Give space after comma, full stop, hyphen, exclamation mark 
    var newValue = $control.val().replace(/([\,\.\-\!])(\w)/g, '$1 $2');
    $control.val(newValue);
    $(this).capitalize();
  }).capitalize();

  $('textarea#comment').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var $control = $(e.currentTarget);
    // Give space after comma, full stop, hyphen, exclamation mark 
    var newValue = $control.val().replace(/([\,\.\-\!])(\w)/g, '$1 $2');
    $control.val(newValue);
    $(this).capitalize();
  }).capitalize();

  $('input#email').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase());
  });      

});
```

I've created an example at https://jsfiddle.net/r4w43L2k/5/, you could check it.

Comment: Thank you very Trung, it's working great. I really appreciated your help.

Comment: This code does not work, there's no `e` in your functions. Don't overuse jQuery, just do `var newValue = this.value.…; this.value = newValue;`. Or even better move that into the `capitalize` method instead of repeating it in every event handler.

Comment: @Bergi But it's working, I have updated it, check, LIVE EXAMPLE, link in question above. If there is something wrong, then please clear the whole code.